# Nomenclature of K2(PdCl4)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

In the compound $\ce{K2[PdCl4]}$, the oxidation state of Pd is +2 so as per the  nomenclature rules, the name of the central metal inside the coordination is simple if it's a cation.

So if we name the compound it comes to be potassium **tetrachloridopalladium(II)** but in the answer it is **tetrachloridopalladate(II)**.

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: It is an anion, not a neutral complex. If it was neutral, it would be IV, not II.

Comment: @poutnik can you please show how it's an anion ?

Comment: Any one of them works

Comment: Like if we say the O.N of Pd is x

Comment: Then +1(2)+x+(-1)4= 0 so x = +2

Comment: It's a cation then

Comment: @Poutnik I didn't get this

Comment: Imagine $\ce{Pd^2+}$ coordinates 2-4 $\ce{Cl-}$, having the overall charge 0 .. -2

Comment: As it has negative charge, its name ends -ate, not -ium.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{K2PdCl4}$ consists of two entities: $\ce{K+}$ cation and $\ce{[PdCl4]^2-}$ anion. This anion is a complex anion and is named accordingly. The rules for formulating and naming coordination compounds are presented in Chapter IR-9 of the current version of [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (Red Book)*](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf). An abridged version is included in the IUPAC Technical Report [Brief guide to the nomenclature of inorganic chemistry. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2015,** *87*(9–10), 1039–1049](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718) as well as in the corresponding four-sided lift-out document, which is available as [supplementary material](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2015.87.issue-9-10/pac-2014-0718/suppl/pac-2014-0718_Suppl.pdf).

Names of anionic coordination entities are given the ending ‘ate’. The **oxidation number** of the central atom may be indicated by a **Roman numeral** in parentheses to the central atom name; alternatively, the **charge on the coordination entity** may be indicated in **integers**. While writing the complex, the cation is placed before the anion and no individual charges are shown.

The systematic name of the entire compound is formed by combining the name of the electropositive constituent, cited first, with that of the electronegative constituent, both suitably qualified by any necessary multiplicative prefixes. The two parts of the name are separated by a space.

So, the systematic name of the complex is **potassium tetrachloridopalladate(II)** or **potassium tetrachloridopalladate(2-)** . This roman numeral is the oxidation state of palladium which is +2 and when writing in terms of charge, the overall charge of the entity is given, in this case, it is -2. Also, do note that the ligand name ‘chloro’ is obsolete. According to current IUPAC recommendations, the correct ligand name is ‘chlorido’.

Read [IUPAC name of a salt made of both cationic and anionic complexes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/iupac-name-of-a-salt-made-of-both-cationic-and-anionic-complexes) for more information.